how to implement revisioning in mysql?
I have a table called tasks that contains the following columns:

id
title
description

I want to implement revisioning to this table,
I know two approaches:

create a table called tasks_revisions, and store a snapshot of each revision
this could be done with two approaches:


store them as JSON in a column called data or




id
revision_id
data




1
1
{"id":1, "title": "x", "description": "y"}


1
2
{"id":1, "title": "x", "description": "z"}




store each column in tasks in the same column name in tasks_revisions




id
revision_id
task_id
task_title
task_description




1
1
1
x
y


1
2
1
x
z




create a table called tasks_revisions, and store only the differences.




id
revision_id
data




1
1
{"id":1, "title": "x", "description": "y"}


2
2
{"description": "z"}


3
3
{"title": "y"}



My question is, which approach is better when data grows? Are there any other approaches?

which approach is better when data grows? What is "data growth" in the amount of rows? And what operations are performed with this data, except new row insertion and complete row retrieving.

usually you want to know also when the changes occurred so you would need to add such column. Json is as bad as comma separated string, you should avoid that

@Akina consider having 10000 rows of tasks and each task has a minimum of 10 revisions, I would like to show revisions only, I don't want to perform something like search, etc.

100k total rows? This is small table. So I'd recommend you to store your data in either normalized form (variant 2, preferred) or serialized form (variant 1). Variant 3 is not safe, it needs in complex query which uses recursive CTE for actual state calculation. Also in MariaDB you may use built-in Temporal Tables.

Consider switching to MariaDB, which has a form of revisioning built in.
https://www.google.com/search?q=mariadb+versioning&oq=mariadb+versioning
Meanwhile, you will probably not notice any other differences between MySQL and MariaDB.

I read a little about it, it is like storing all the data in the same or separate table, the thing that MariaDB provides is that this versioning is managed by MariaDB, and you have some options and don't need additional effort, for example, you can ignore some columns from versioning. I don't want to migrate to MariaDB right now, thanks for your help

Which option is better, it really all depends on the application and how you want to query the data? Do you want to keep the previous revisions indefinitely or do you want to truncate it at some point? Which point? You want to keep X revisions or you want to keep up to 1 month/1 year/5 years worth of revisions?
If you want to query all columns, it would be easier to index them properly when you use separate columns and not JSON. If you want to keep data for some period of time, you would need timestamp column and use it as a partitioning key. Storing deltas in JSON format probably won’t make sense unless there’s a specific use case. In your example, to generate latest data, instead of reading one row with last revision you have to read three and then combine it on the application side - probably a waste of resources.
So, to sum it up, it all depends on the application. I would lean towards traditional approach with data split to columns - easier to index if you want to look for some particular data. If you do not need that, storing data as JSON may make sense, especially if your application deals with that format quite well. But then what you are implementing is a key - value store and I would wonder why use MySQL for that? Sure, it can be used but there are better solutions that can be used to implement such data structure.
